Unable to delete profile information on Facebook
some years ago,I added my then-husband's work info and high school to my Facebook about me section because he wasn't on Facebook and a lot of his family were,etc. Now that we are divorced, I'd like to remove that information, but it is in a lighter font and when I click on "edit" in those sections,only my information is available to remove or change.Thank you!

What do you you mean you added his work "info & high school" to your account because he wasn't on Facebook? How did FB show it was his info not yours? It's difficult to follow what you did and the problem. [Edit] to include URLs being discussed (anonymize your FB handle for privacy). This will help us understand what part of the interface you are in. eg. Overview https://www.facebook.com/<your_fb_account>/about_overview or Work and Education https://www.facebook.com/<your_fb_account>/about_work_and_education Screenshots would also help if you can anonymize you & your ex's info.

Welcome to Web Applications. Consider registering your account to avoid accidentally losing access to your content by switching devices, browsers, or clearing your cookies. Registering is quick and you gain access to more site features. For more info see Why should I register my account?

Can you add one or two screenshots of how it looks when you try to do it?
